# Threading using python in raspberry pi for gpio inputs

Tags: python, multithreading, raspberry-pi3

Doubt in Threading in gpio pins raspberry pi

my self working on encoders of differential drive robot, i need to read the speed and podition of wheels using two encoders simultaneously. I have used threading library in python even though i started both the functions only the function which has been initiated at first runs while the second doesn't. I am not sure what the resson is , is there anything to be noted while using threading in gpio pins of raspberry pi 3b, if so please help and suggest a solution.

```
from threading import Thread
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import datetime 

def encoder_right(t1):
  
   ...
        
def encoder_left(t1):
    
    
   ...

t1 = datetime.datetime.now()

Thread1 = Thread(target = encoder_right(t1),daemon = True)

Thread2 = Thread(target = encoder_left(t1),daemon = True)

Thread1.start()

Thread2.start()

Thread1.join()

Thread1.join()
```

Comment: If we're going to help you understand why only one function seems to be running we would need to see your code. Without that we're just guessing, and that's neither helpful to you nor a good use of our time.

Comment: i have added the code please provide a solution

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new `threading.Thread` object, you need to pass a function to the `target` parameter. In your code, instead of passing the function object, you are *calling* the function. That is, when you write:

```
Thread1 = Thread(target=encoder_right(t1), daemon=True)
```

You are *calling* `encoder_right(t1)`; your code never gets beyond this point because you've entered an infinite loop. You never create a thread and you never reach the lines after this code.

You want to write instead:

```
Thread1 = Thread(target=encoder_right, args=(t1,), daemon=True)
Thread2 = Thread(target=encoder_left, args=(t1,), daemon=True)
```

This way you're passing the function object in the `target` parameter, and the `Thread` object will take care of starting the function in a new thread.

---

Unrelated to your question, but you only need to call `GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)` and `GPIO.setwarnings(False)` once in your program; you don't need to call that in each thread. That is, you could write instead:

```
def encoder_right(t1):
    ...


def encoder_left(t1):
    ...

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

t1 = datetime.datetime.now()

Thread1 = Thread(target=encoder_right, args=(t1,), daemon=True)
Thread2 = Thread(target=encoder_left, args=(t1,), daemon=True)

Thread1.start()
Thread2.start()

Thread1.join()
Thread2.join()
```

Also! I would avoid giving variables the same name as your functions (e.g., in your function `encoder_left` you also have a variable named `encoder_left`). At some point this is going to cause a surprising problem when you try to reference the function and find that you're actually referencing an integer value instead.

Comment: Thanks it is working as expected now  :)